# Json LocalDateTIme issue

Tags: java, json, kotlin

```
Exception during serialization - message:  
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "2021-05-04T09:06:27-05:00":  
Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: 
(java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2021-05-04T09:06:27-05:00'
```

```kotlin
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING )
    @JsonProperty("inprogress_ts")
    val inProgressTs: LocalDateTime
```

Why can't this `@JsonFormat` pattern parse the `String` `"2021-05-04T09:06:27-05:00"`?

Comment: I have used  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING ) but this is not working

Comment: This is **not** a `String` you can directly convert to a `LocalDateTime` because it contains an offset (`-05:00`). Use an `OffsetDateTime`, that should work...

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because you are using a non suitable data type / class:

A `LocalDateTime` does not consider offsets, it simply has none and cannot parse `String`s containing an offset.
Your `String` contains `-05:00`, which will cause the `DateTimeParseException` being thrown.

Use a suitable class: An `OffsetDateTime` instead.

Comment: ZonedDateTime would also fit.

Answer (score 0):

The string your are passing hasn´t got the same format than JsonFormat:

```
2021-05-04     T    09:06:27    -05:00
yyyy-MM-dd    'T'   HH:mm:ss    ??????
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include zone then it should work. I have written a sample extension function in kotlin may help

```
fun String.convertDateString(): String {
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ENGLISH)
    val date: Date = dateFormat.parse(this) ?: Date()
    val outFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
    return outFormat.format(date)
}
```

Input: "2021-05-04T09:06:27-05:00"

Formatted Response: "May 04, 2021".

Actual date : 2021-05-04T16:06:27.000+0200 (GMT+2:00 time zone)

Answer (score 0):

I have formatted like below  and then converted manually

```
    @JsonProperty("event_ts")


val packedCentralTime = eventTs.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")).toLocalDateTime()
```